# How to summerize Parent data on the same tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Temp table(in stored procedure) lets say #tempTable which holds an **id, id_name** and **amount** , the Detail id(4 chars id) is the only row which has non NULL **amount** value.

```
id      id_name  Amount
1       Main1    NULL
11      Header1  NULL
1101    Detail1  2
1102    Detail2  7  
12      Header2  NULL
1201    Detail3  5 
1202    Detail4  3
```

What i want is a query to summarize amount with id nested in it's own id like :

> amount 11 = amount 1101 + amount 1102 (because 11 is in 2 first detail's left chars)
>
> amount 12 = amount 1201 + amount 1202 (because 12 is in 2 first detail's left chars)
>
> and
>
> amount 1 = amount 11 + amount 12 (because 1 is in first detail's left chars)

```
id      id_name  Amount
1       Main1    17
11      Header1  9
1101    Detail1  2
1102    Detail2  7  
12      Header2  8
1201    Detail3  5 
1202    Detail4  3
```

What i've done

```
SELECT t.id
, t.id_name
, CASE LEN(t.id)
    WHEN 2 
         THEN (SELECT SUM(t2.Amount) FROM #tempTable t2 WHERE LEFT(t2.id,2) = t.id) and LEN(t2.id) > 2)
    WHEN 1 
         THEN (SELECT SUM(t2.Amount) FROM #tempTable t2 WHERE LEFT(t2.id,1) = t.id) and LEN(t2.id) = 2)
    ELSE t1.amount
END
FROM #tempTable t
```

But it leaves me with

```
id      id_name  Amount
1101    Detail1  2
1102    Detail2  7  
1201    Detail3  5 
1202    Detail4  3
```

how supposed i solve this?

ps : sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language, nor second or even third :D..

**Update**
To answer [Lajos Arpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504803/how-to-summerize-parent-data-on-the-same-tables#comment66332984_39506018) Comment

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zUzj.png)

Comment: Have you considered adding a nullable column that refers to the parent ID? It will make your problem a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following script to get the desired result. The sub select within the main select is ignoring the NULL values in amounts.

```
SELECT t.id
, t.id_name
, CASE LEN(t.id)
    WHEN 2 
         THEN ISNULL((SELECT SUM(t2.Amount) FROM #tempTable t2 WHERE t2.id = t.id) and LEN(t2.id) = 2),0)
    WHEN 1 
         THEN ISNULL((SELECT SUM(t3.Amount) FROM #tempTable t3 WHERE t3.id= t.id) and LEN(t3.id) = 1),0)
    ELSE ISNULL(t1.amount,0)
END
FROM #tempTable t
```

Comment: "LEN(t2.id) = 2 should be LEN(t2.id) > 2" and the other " = 2" but this help me much by adding ISNULL function.. THANKS!!!

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT t.id
, t.id_name
, t1.TotalAmount
FROM #tempTable t
OUTER APPLY (   SELECT SUM(t2.Amount) AS TotalAmount 
                FROM #tempTable t2 
                WHERE CAST(t2.ID AS VARCHAR(4)) LIKE CAST(t.ID AS VARCHAR(4)) + '%' 
                ) AS t1
GROUP BY t.id
    , t.id_name
```

Comment: There was mistake in the LIKE clause table alias, I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's attack the problem as we should in general, asking particular questions and generalizing them in each step until we find the general answer. First, we need to be able to find our groups:

```
select LEFT(id, 2) AS id_group, Amount
from #tempTable;
```

Now, we need to form our groups and aggregate the answer:

```
select id_group, sum(Amount) as amnt
from (select LEFT(id, 2) AS id_group, Amount
      from #tempTable) t
group by id_group;
```

Comment: not work, it's showing |id_group |amnt
1 |NULL|
11 |9|
12 |8|            but thanks

Comment: How is this different from your expectations and why? I expected the result you have shown.